# Python: Copy+paste the same lines or call a function instead?

Tags: python

I don't know what to do here.

I'm writing a scraper where I need to scrape some data and the code is getting kinda long because of the copy+paste I'm making in my 'for loop', problem is I feel the code is a lot slower when I make a function I call with arguments instead of calling the same lines. Can someone help me explain if it's just me or is there some reasoning behind it? Also, what is most preferable in general?

***Option 1 (without function, but copy+pasting the code):***

```
for i in soup.find("div", class_="bets betCols2"):

    """ 0.5 """
    if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text == 'Total Over 0.5':
        odd = i.find('span', 'koeff').text
        mylist.append(odd)

    if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text == 'Total Under 0.5':
        odd = i.find('span', 'koeff').text
        mylist.append(odd)
```

***Option 2 (with function):***

```
def find_info(soup, betinfo, mylist):

    for i in soup.find("div", class_="bets betCols2"):
        if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text == betinfo:
            odd = i.find('span', 'koeff').text
            mylist.append(odd)

    return mylist

find_info(soup, 'Total Over 0.5', mylist)
find_info(soup, 'Total Under 0.5', mylist)
```

Comment: Look up the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Option 3: `if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text in ('Total Over 0.5', 'Total Under 0.5'):`

Comment: Also, note that your two variants are not equivalent, as the second calls `soup.find` twice. If anything, I would make just the `if` a function, but as above comment, you don't actually have to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that your two codes are not equvalent: The second version will call `soup.find` *twice*. Instead, you could wrap just the `if` part in a function. You could even define this function within the outer loop so it requires fewer parameters and does not clutter the remaining code:

```
for i in soup.find("div", class_="bets betCols2"):
    def find_info(what):
        if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text == what:
            odd = i.find('span', 'koeff').text
            mylist.append(odd)
    find_info('Total Over 0.5')
    find_info('Total Under 0.5')
```

Note that this still calls `i.find` twice (or four times). You could store those in temporary variables, but there's another way: Since the body of the `if` is the same, and you are just comparing the result of `i.find` to different values:

```
for i in soup.find("div", class_="bets betCols2"):
    if i.find('span', 'bet_type').text in ('Total Over 0.5', 'Total Under 0.5'):
        odd = i.find('span', 'koeff').text
        mylist.append(odd)
```

This way, there's no duplication, no nested functions, and it is IMHO much clearer what the code is doing.

Comment: Tobias so much thank you. Not only did you improve my code, you also teach and explain everything in details! Thank you stackoverflow and thank you Tobias!

Answer (score 0):

There's theory and skill involved. You understand the theory part: you see your program getting kinda long and difficult to maintain because of the cut & paste. That's one of the main reasons to split out a function. By using functions you should end of with less code and should be easier to maintain / update in the future.

Then there's the skill: breaking the program into **good** functions. That's your problem here (at least in your example). You've got a lot of repeated work (I'm all for making the computer do more work than the programmer, but let's not over do it.) @tobias_k in the initial comments has some useful suggestions here.

Comment: I hear you! I'm looking at Tobias' answer and I'll sure remember this in the future. Thank you also for showing me where I need to improve!